# $templateCache is undefined In directive though I set `{cache: $templateCache}` in $http call

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I have two html pages, `snippet1.html` & `snippet2.html`. I want use them inside my directive. Because I'm going to add multiple template by using single directive.

I tried this thing with by adding html templates inside `<script>` tag & gave `type="text/ng-template"` to them like Below.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="snippet1.html">
    <div>Here is Snippet one</div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="snippet2.html">
    <div>Here is Snippet two</div>
</script>
```

And then I use `$templateCache.get('snippet1.html')`. This implementation is working Fine.

But in my case I need to load them from html itself, so I decided to load template by ajax and make `$http` `cache: $templateCache`

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzX9z/41/)

**Run Block**

```
myApp.run(['$templateCache','$http', function($templateCache, $http){ 
  $http.get('snippet1.html',{ cache : $templateCache }); 
  $http.get('snippet2.html',{ cache : $templateCache }); 
}]);
```

But inside my controller `$templateCache.get('snippet1.html')` is undefined.

My question is, Why it is working while i declared template inside `<script>' tag & Why it don't work when I html inside`$templateCache`while making`$http` ajax call?

[**Plunkr With Problem**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rjmLXR1YWaqWGgzPbpwE?p=preview)

Can anyone help me out with this issue? Or I'm missing anything in code.

Help would greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting issue, and I can offer an interesting workaround and my thoughts on what is going on. I think a better solution may exist, but finding such solutions also proved to be a challenge. Nonetheless, I think the main issue is simply your `console.log($templateCache.get('snippet1.html'))` is returning `undefined` because of the race condition with your `$http.get`'s not resolving first.

Examining the api for [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache), I couldn't find any sort of helpful way of knowing when templates resolve requested via ajax. To see the simple issue, run this in your directive to see some basic information about what is currently stored in your `$templateCache`

```
console.log($templateCache.info())
```

With the result of

> *Object {id: "templates", size: 0}*

For observing the core of the issue, run the same JS in the directive, but with a timeout as such

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($templateCache.info())
}, 1000);
```

With the result of

> *Object {id: "templates", size: 2}*

Interesting, so they're in there... but getting a handle on them is now the challenge. I crafted the following workaround to at least give us something for now. Inject `$q` and `$rootScope` into your `.run` function as such

```
myApp.run(['$templateCache', '$http', '$q', '$rootScope', function($templateCache, $http, $q, $rootScope){ 
    $q.all([
        $http.get('snippet1.html',{ cache : $templateCache }),
        $http.get('snippet2.html',{ cache : $templateCache }) 
    ]).then(function(resp){
        $rootScope.templateCache = resp
    })
  }]
);
```

Examining this, you'll notice I place an arbitrary `var` on our `$rootScope` as such `$rootScope.templateCache` for the purpose of placing a `$watch` on it in our directive. Then in our directive, let's call into our `$templateCache` when we then know there is a value on `$rootScope.templateCache`, indicating the `$q` service has resolved our promises as such

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$parent.$parent.$watch('templateCache', function(n, o) {
        if(n) {
            element.append($compile($templateCache.get('snippet1.html')[1])(scope));
        }
    });
}
```

And hey look! Our template directive is correctly rendered. The hacky looking `scope.$parent.$parent` is because in this directive, we have isolated our `scope` and now need to climb some ladders to get the value defined on `$rootScope`.

Do I hope we can find a cleaner more consise way? Of course! But, hopefully this identifies *why* this is happening and a possible approach to get up and running for now. Working plunker provided below.

### [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/aQKymmorxTM2m5vyJ4MU?p=preview)

### Edit

Here is a completely different approach to solve this which involves manual bootstrapping

```
var providers = {};

var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

$injector.invoke(function($http, $q, $templateCache, $document) {
    $q.all([
        $http.get('snippet1.html',{ cache : $templateCache }),
        $http.get('snippet2.html',{ cache : $templateCache }) 
        ]).then(function(resp){
            providers.cacheProvider = $templateCache;
            angular.bootstrap($document, ['myApp']);
        });
    });

myApp
.controller('test',function() {
})
.directive('myTemplate', function ($templateCache, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            snippets: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.append($compile(providers.cacheProvider.get('snippet1.html')[1])(scope));
        }
    };
});
```

### [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNSLsUaIDbeAIhADt8xo?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for spend your suspicious time.I think no need to put watch, direct use `$timeout` inside directive is working.here is plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/DFdS7zsnlEPefpWEC3zG?p=preview ..but i don't understand why we need to put `$templateCache.get('snippet1.html')[1]`?

Comment: `$timeout` may not always guarantee results. What if your ajax call takes 2000ms for some odd reason? The reason for [1] is because a detailed object is returned back and index 1 is the markup you want.

Comment: Oh. got it..`templateCache` is defined in `$rootScope` then why we need to say `$parent.$parent` while putting watch?

Comment: Correct, and we do this because only `$rootScope` can be injected into `.run` and our directive isolate scope directive causes us to traverse up the scope inheritance tree a bit

Comment: just played with plunkr,  Instead of `scope.$watch` used `$rootScope.$watch` working fine.no need mention $parent.$parent hierarchy.

Comment: ah nice, I'd think that's a cleaner way

Comment: Appreciated your answer. Thanks for spending your valuable time. I believe there might/might not be a good a way that. I'll wait for other answers.

Comment: Have you found any alternative solutions for this?

Comment: No i didn't found any alternative, actually what i was thinking is to load controller and directive after a template promise gets completed inside run block. is it possible?

Comment: @pankajparkar I have provided you an alternative approach which I feel will solve your issue in a way like you have just mentioned. I hope this will be an acceptable answer for you

Comment: I accepted your answer, but didn't replied on what i asked in previous comment

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior.  When you include a template inside of a script tag, angular finds it during the bootstrap process and adds it to the cache before any code runs.  That's why it is available in your directive.

When you use $templateCache.put() (or use $http.get to retrieve an html file as you specify in your code, angular has to use ajax to resolve the template.  While the request is "in flight", the template cache doesn't know anything about it - the file is only added to the template cache after the response is received.

Since your directive runs as part of the first digest cycle (on startup), there will never be any remote files in the cache, so you get the error you see.

The "correct" way to do what you are trying to do is to not use the $templateCache directly, but rather use the $http service to request the remote template.  If the original response has returned, $http will just call $templateCache.get for you.  If it hasn't, it will return the same promise that the original $http request generated.

Doing it this way, there will be no requirement to use $timeout or $watch.  The template will be compiled as soon as it is available using promises.

```
myApp.controller('test',function(){})
    .directive("myTemplate", function ($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            template: '&?myTemplate',
            src: '&?'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $http.get(scope.template() || scope.src()).then(function(result) {
                element.append($compile(result.data)(scope));
            });
        }
    };
});

<my-template src="snippet1.html"></my-template>
```

or

```
<div my-template="snippet1.html"></div>
```

[Here is a working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/T12vyo1CCf1maYKkeHIW?p=preview)

EDIT:  Alternative without $compile and $http

```
myApp.controller('test',function(){})
    .directive("myTemplate", function ($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            snippets: '='
        },
        template: 'snippet1.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
});
```

As to your final question (why you have to use [1] to get the html - $http service does not store only html in the cache - it stores a data structure that may contain a promise or the element (if loaded from a script tag).  Since it knows what it put in, it knows how to get it out.  When you short circuit things you're only guessing.

Long story short - don't use $templateCache to resolve templates yourself.

EDIT:  Code from $http demonstrating the different types of data that might be stored in the cache.

```
if (cache) {
    cachedResp = cache.get(url);
    if (isDefined(cachedResp)) {
      if (isPromiseLike(cachedResp)) {
        // cached request has already been sent, but there is no response yet
        cachedResp.then(resolvePromiseWithResult, resolvePromiseWithResult);
      } else {
        // serving from cache
        if (isArray(cachedResp)) {
          resolvePromise(cachedResp[1], cachedResp[0], shallowCopy(cachedResp[2]), cachedResp[3]);
        } else {
          resolvePromise(cachedResp, 200, {}, 'OK');
        }
      }
    } else {
      // put the promise for the non-transformed response into cache as a placeholder
      cache.put(url, promise);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer `$templateCache.get('snippet1.html')[0]` doesn't have value, getting undefined..I believe while accessing first DOM we always do `element[0]` why same thing not applied here?

Comment: element[0] works because the actual DOM element is wrapped in a jQuery object (which is actually an Array).  That's not what is going on here.  The item returned by $templateCache.get may be a promise, an array with the stored results of a resolved $http promise (what you are seeing here), or an angular.element.  I've pasted the relevant code from $http to my answer to show how $http handles what is returned by $templateCache.get().

Comment: Cool..I'm having around 10 templates like snippet1.html & snippet2.html.. Will it be good way to load template using $http call inside a directive

Comment: Yes, but an easier way is to just use the template property of the directive definition.  See updated answer.

Comment: But that is only for one template `snippet1.html`, you mean to say for 10 templates i need to write the directive 10 times? How can i render different template dynamically?

Comment: I don't know your exact use case, but you should look at ng-include.  However, if you need something more than ng-include, see the next edit.  It essentially is identical to what hg-include would be doing.

Comment: My use case is simple there are more than 10 template, i want to add html on basis of condition from directive. i can't put them inside script tag with `type="text/ng-template"` because of some business logic..as you suggested `ng-include`, I think using `ng-include` will make isolated scope, and they may lead to use `$parent` to use scope of parent html of `ng-include` directive. that get messy while handling scope.

Comment: Would need to see your code, but ngInclude creates a child scope, not an isolated scope.  It should work just fine, although I'd make sure to use dot notation on all of your ngModels inside the templates.  No need to use $parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70868/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-joe-enzminger).